# Utilizar FOR para utilizar los nombres de archivos .bat

Tags: batch, script

Estoy teniendo un problema al intentar hacer que mi script lea todos los archivos de una carpeta para asignar unas variables.

En este momento funciona como lo tengo con una lista en la que hago el set de la ruta del archivo.

¿Existe alguna forma para que en vez de utilizar ese primer FOR el script recorra la carpeta servers y use en el 2º FOR los nombres de los archivos que ha recorrido antes?

El script

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%c in (servers\lista.txt) do (
    %%c
)
for %%a in (%s1% %s2% %s3%) do (
    call :start %%a
)
```

Archivo lista:

```
set s1=servers\xxx.txt
set s2=servers\yyy.txt
set s3=servers\zzz.txt
```

Carpeta servers contiene el archivo `lista.txt` y los archivos `xxx.txt`, `yyy.txt`, `zzz.txt`, etc.

Disculpa que me he explicado un poco mal. En los archivos xxx.txt yyy.txt etc. solo hay varios set de otras variables como la direccion ip o el nombre de usuario.

lo que busco es que el segundo for en vez de utilizar las variables que yo le paso en lista.txt use todos los archivos de la carpeta servers, en este ejemplo xxx.txt yyy.txt zzz.txt referenciados como s1 s2 y s3.

---

Disculpa que me he explicado un poco mal. 
En los archivos xxx.txt yyy.txt etc. solo hay varios set de otras variables como la direccion ip o el nombre de usuario.

lo que busco es que el segundo for en vez de utilizar las variables que yo le paso en lista.txt use todos los archivos de la carpeta servers, en este ejemplo xxx.txt yyy.txt zzz.txt referenciados como s1 s2 y s3.

Comment: Veamos. Que quieres un FOR o dos FOR? En el primer for quieres ejecutar cada una de las líneas del fichero lista.txt. En el segundo for quieres hacer lo mismo, pero en vez de con un sólo fichero, lo quieres hacer con 3, y en esos tres ficheros .txt hay línea con ficheros .bat? Vendría bien tener ejemplos de que contiene cada archivo.